# Angular - What other issues can cause offsetHeight to remain "0"?

Tags: javascript, angular, offsetheight

I need to know a rendered element's height.  I don't care if the element reports it or if the parent detects the height.

I've been researching this issue and I the number one root cause is that the :host element must have its `display:block` set and I've done that. (Did I do it at the right level?)

`this.nativeElement` dumps great info to the console.log but when I try to programmatically access the value it comes up "0".

Files:

img-fader.component.html

```
<img [src]='imgSrc' class="item carousel-item" style="width: 100%; display: block;"/>
```

img-fader.component.css

```
:host {
    display: block;
}

img.carousel-item {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
}
```

img-fader.component.ts (Significant Portions)

```
export class ImgFaderComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ContentChildren(ImgFaderComponent, {read: ElementRef}) imgList: QueryList<ElementRef>;

  constructor() {}

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.imgList.forEach(img => console.log('Img: ', img.nativeElement.children[0].offsetHeight));
  }
}
```

Comment: There is load event for img tag.

Comment: An image has no dimensions until it has loaded

Comment: Ok, so how do I hook into that event?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is still struggling with similar issues with image offsetHeight, I figured out that if you wrap the command to get offsetHeight withing a **setTimeout** function, you then get the image height (and width I suppose) correctly.

This happens because asynchronous commands run to the next cycle, so the image has loaded then.